# Jquery ui position, cannot make it relative to current item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).tooltip({
            items: "#tabs .word-list li .invisible",
            position: {
                my: "right center",
                at: "left center",
                of: $(this).parent()
            } 
        });
```

`of` part never works, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, easier solution was to ditch jquery-ui-tooltip and make my own...

```
$(document).on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                //
                $(this).empty().html('<div class="tooltip">' + $(this).attr("title") + '</div>');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                //
                $(this).empty();
            }
        }, "#tabs .word-list li .invisible");
```

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried just setting `my` and `at` and removing `of`?

By default, the tooltip is positioned relative to the element, setting the `of` may be making it relative to the document.

```
$(".ParentClass").tooltip({
            items: "#tabs .word-list li .invisible",
            position: {
                my: "right center",
                at: "left center",
                of: this
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But problem I'm facing is that .invisible moves, as it's parent increases size on hover. I wanted to set of->parent so I could fix tooltip to the parent top and thus avoid all shaking and weird spacing.

Comment: Have you tried setting the tooltip for the items instead of of using `items`?  I updated to answer to show what I mean, although you may want commas between those.  I'm not sure what you're querying for with that selector.

Comment: Yes, actually my original question (if you check edits) postulated that $this was referring to document. Problem is, .invisible is not part of html but is generated via js after page load. So I need document.

Comment: You're going to have to initialize the tool tip for `.invisible` when you load them via javascript. Right now you're setting the position relative to the document.

Comment: what's the parent element name?  You can set the tooltip for the parent and not document.  I updated my answer to show what I mean.  Using the parent as the selector you can just set the of to `this`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation:  http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

of (default: null)
Type: Selector or Element or jQuery or Event
Which element to position against. If you provide a selector or jQuery object, the first matching element will be used. If you provide an event object, the pageX and pageY properties will be used. Example: "#top-menu"

Why do you assume the 'of' does not work?

For example, does the parent have many matching elements?  Maybe you need to provide a selector then?  http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector

Without seeing the parent HTML body you may not have provided enough information to debug.

Comment: I believe, $(this) inside of refers to $(document). This is why it doesn't work.